Extracting Phone Extension Number If exist
I have some data I am trying to cleanup. I have two fields called Phone and Ext. Phone has values that are blank or in format of:

(800) 555-9876
(800) 555-1234 x__________
(800) 555-1234 x0123______

Ext is mostly empty but will sometimes have a value like 'x1234' or just '1234'
I used the following code to split on  x and pull the first element:
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.split(' x').str[0]

This works to extract just the phone # part but if I did .str[1] to extract any potential extension, I would receive an error because a lot of the rows do not have the  x_________ field.
Is there a way to extract the extension from the phone # if it exists and move it to the Ext field and clean up the Phone field?

You could use str.extract with a short regex:
df[['Phone', 'Ext']] = df['Phone'].str.extract(r'^(.*?)(?: (x.*))?$')

Or split+reindex:
df[['Phone', 'Ext']] = df['Phone'].str.split(r' (?=x)', n=1, expand=True).reindex(columns=[0,1])

reindex is needed in case no row has an extension, which would return a single row and cause the assignment to fail.
Output:
            Phone          Ext
0  (800) 555-9876          NaN
1  (800) 555-1234  x__________
2  (800) 555-1234  x0123______

If you want to fill the empty Ext with the existing Ext if any, add a fillna:
df[['Phone', 'Ext']] = (df['Phone'].str.split(r' (?=x)', n=1, expand=True).reindex(columns=[0,1])
                        .fillna({1: df['Ext']})
                        )

